# Laravel storage public url after storage:link not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-storage

I'm trying to access the public images on my server via URL on the browser.

To do this, I have the following hierarchy in my storage folder:

```
storage
   |app
     |public
        |post
           |1
             |myimage.png
```

I then ran the following command to create a link

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Now when I try access my image on the browser via http://localhost:8000/storage/post/1/myimage.png I get a **404 NOT FOUND** page.

I even tried http://localhost:8000/post/1/myimage.png, same thing.

Here are my settings in my **filesystems.php** file:

```php
'disks' => [
    ...,
    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
    ...,
],

'links' => [
    public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
],
```

Am I doing this all wrong?

Comment: On what port did you run project?

Comment: @EhsanAhmadiKian Port 8000, I actually forgot to add it in the question, will edit it now

Comment: `I even tried http://localhost/post/1/myimage.png, same thing.`. is this right url. i mean you did not mention port number in link

Comment: @ApurvBhavsar I've just edited the question, I missed out the port. The url is actually `http://localhost:8000/post/1/myimage.png` . It doesn't work with or without port number

Comment: did you see the `storage` shortcut generated in public folder?

Comment: @ApurvBhavsar I didn't actually, just realised hmm... `php artisan storage:link` says the link is created, but no shortcut

Comment: Thanks for the help @EhsanAhmadiKian, I was able to find a solution to my problem :)

Comment: Thanks for the help @ApurvBhavsar, I was able to find a solution to my problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution to my public images dilemma.

I'm no longer storing images in `/storage/public` and creating a symbolic link, but in the `/public` folder from root directly.

I had to add a configuration in the `/config/filesystems.php` file like so:

```
'disks' => [
    ...,
    'root_public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => public_path('/'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL'),
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
    ...,
],
```

With this, my public directories and images are accessed via `http://localhost:8000/mypublicpath/myimage.png`

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue on NGINX, all files in `storage` folder were returning error 404.
The solution was to add a `location` block indicating the `root` folder.

```
location ~* ^/storage/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
    root /var/www/project_root_folder;
}
```

Replace `project_root_folder` with your actual path to the Laravel folder which contains `storage`, `config`, `app` folders etc.